# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: mysql, django

when I used command "python manage.py makemigrations"(the same with typing "python manage.py runserver"),it threw this error.And then I checked the authority of the users.
The code and result are as fllows.

```
mysql> select host,user from mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| host      | user          |
+-----------+---------------+
| %         | root          |
| %         | zhuxin        |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
| localhost | zhuxin        |
+-----------+---------------+


mysql> show grants for 'zhuxin'@'%'; 
+---------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Grants for zhuxin@%                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zhuxin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION | 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `blogdb`.* TO 'zhuxin'@'%'            |  
+---------------------------------------------------------------+ 

mysql> show grants for 'root'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                | 
+--------------------------------------------------+ 
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'                 | 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `blogdb`.* TO 'root'@'%' |  
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried everything to solve it, but for no use.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with the grants within the mysql database itself. your
mention of these input statements, brought my attention to such a thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to make changes in **project settings.py**. Provide `USER` and `PASSWORD` for your database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'rootpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yeah,I have changed the settings.py like this:                                   DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'blogdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': '', 
        'PORT': '', 
    }   
}.    But the error is still threw

Comment: @朱朱鑫, Have you checked if with this user and password if you are able to authenticate to mysql server?

Comment: Thks. I get it ! I change the "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" when I authorized. But I don't know why. Maybe it is like what you say that I confused the users.

Comment: @朱朱鑫,  That's nice to hear, If my solution helped you, the please select the answer. Thanks for all the cooperation.

Comment: If you're getting this error while deploying to AWS elastic beanstalk, you just have to go into your configuration from the console and make sure your RDS DB password is updated.

Comment: I was using a file to read the credentials from, and had made a typo in the path. So still something to double check when you get this error :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check Your Database Username and Password. many time,  we do typing mistake. it doesn't match from the database username and password so occur this error. I faced this error and trust me, it is my very bad experience.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: This could actually be one solution. I had built a dockerized microservice for which I copied an env var from another similar ms. I created an user with a different password than the one in this env var file, and had issues when running makemigrations.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and changing the `HOST` to `127.0.0.1` and removing the password worked for me. You can try it out and see if it will work for you as well.

Comment: this case for me. MySQL didn't allow remote connexions. Using the IP seemed to be considered as a remote connexion. Using `localhost` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error message after copying my project onto a new machine from a backup file. An additional error message explained the problem:

```
[Warning] World-writable config file '/home/myuser/myproject/database.cnf' is ignored.
```

The permissions of my database configuration file had been changed and it was not being loaded, therefore Django was trying to connect with the wrong user. I fixed this by running:

```
chmod 600 database.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally used **USERNAME**:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'inventory',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'USERNAME': 'root',
    'PORT': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',  # Your Password
}
```

Just change it to **USER**

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the password field if not set.**

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "reservations",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "3306",
        "USER": "root",
    }
}
```

Add this snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

In My case I was using the wrong port number, I have configured the MySql on 3307 and was using 3306 in the `settings.py` file

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
    "NAME": "reservations",
    "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
    "PORT": "3307",
    "USER": "root",
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I learn from linuxnightly.com that it is caused by auth socket plugin, once you disable it the problem is solved.

Try running the following commands after you are logged into mysql as root:

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password_here';
mysql> exit;
$ sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

To make this work, you have to change root's password. This is done by the `UPDATE` command. You have to restart mysql at the end of the process with the `systemctl` command at the end.

source: https://linuxnightly.com/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34656688)